# My device upgraded to IOS 8.1.3 last night and now Xcode will not build for it

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Xcode gives me a error saying :"unable to copy symbols from this device". The error message suggests that the current users running Xcode might not have read/write permissions for the destination folder. I checked that and the user does have read and write permission. An other problem I read about online is that I might not have enough disk space on the Mac for all the symbols that need to be copied. The thing is that I have already freed up 3+Gb of space and I still get the same error. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: This sometimes happens. Try unplugging the device, rebooting it, and restarting Xcode, before reconnecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it needed a bit more space than 3GB. Everything is fine now. The import that XCode did was 2.6GB in size but I think that the OS wanted some breathing room too.

Comment: Are you talking about free disk space on your Mac?